# Submiiting a Form with File input and other inputs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file, file-upload, multer

I want to upload a file with other form data. but when i upload file with different route like router.post(/api/upload)" it works, but i want to upload file along with other form data to route like route.post('/api/complaints') etc. but when i do with route.post('/api/complaints'), the "req.file" is undefined but when i do with router.post(/api/upload), it gets uploaded. Please help.

this is multer configuring

```
const upload = multer({
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10000000
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
      return cb(new Error("File must be .jpg | .jpeg | .png"));
    }
    cb(undefined, true);
  }
});
```

this is the route for uploading file.

```
router.post(
  "/upload",
  upload.single("complaint"),
  async (req, res) => {
    // req.file.buffer;
    res.status(200).send("file uploaded successfully." + req.file.buffer);
  },
  (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  }
);
```

this is the route for posting all form data. Problem is here. here req.file is undefined.

```
router.post(
  "/",
  authComplainer,
  upload.single("complaint"),
  async (req, res) => {

    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.categoryId);

    if (!category) return res.status(400).send("Invalid category.");

    const assignee = await Assignee.findOne({
      responsibility: category
    });
    if (!assignee) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Assignee.");

    const complainer = await Complainer.findById(req.complainer._id);
    if (!complainer) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Complainer.");

    let complaint = new Complaint({
      category: {
        _id: category._id
      },
      complainer: {
        _id: complainer._id
      },
      assignedTo: {
        _id: assignee._id
      },
      geolocation: req.body.geolocation ? req.body.geolocation : "",
      details: req.body.details,
      title: req.body.title,
      location: req.body.location,
      image: req.file ? req.file.buffer : ""
    });

    await complaint.save();
    res.send(complaint);
```

this is my reactjs code

```
 handleFileChange = e => {
    // if (this.checkMimeType(e)) {
    this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] });
}

doSubmit = async () => {
    this.setState({ isDialogOpen: false });
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append(
      "complaint",
      this.state.selectedFile,
      this.state.selectedFile.name
    );

    const newState = { ...this.state.data, data };
    console.log(newState);

    const { data: result } = await saveComplaint(this.state.data);
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });

    console.log(result);
    toast.success("Complaint is successfully registered.");
    // this.props.history.replace("/complainer");
   };
```

i want to upload file along with other form data like input type text etc but its not working. please help. The main problem is in **React.js** code. req.file is undefined when sent from React app. when i tested it from Postmon. it works on both scenarios

Answer (score 0):

So, if you already identified that "the issue if in React.js", then file an issue in React’s github instead!

Comment: Then what is the purpose of Stackoverflow?